# Matlab-for Loop different variable

Tags: matlab

As per your advice with some modification i am able to get values for each iteration but what i need to obtain is Perunc matrix

```
close all
Ebno=0:1:20
snr=db2pow(Ebno)
%Perunc=zeros(length(Ebno),length(q))
for i=1:length(Ebno)
p=qfunc( sqrt(2*snr) )
for q=10:10:50
 Perunc=1-(1-(p)).^q
end
end%
```

Comment: For the error, see the difference between [`mtimes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) and [`times`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html). For storing your data, you are iterating with `j` but you are not using `j` to store anything inside the loop.

Comment: with this modification i am able to run but clear all
close all
Ebno=-20:1:20
snr=db2pow(Ebno)
for i=1:length(Ebno)
p=qfunc( sqrt(2*snr) )
for q=100:10:1000
 Perunc=1-(1-(p)).^q
end
end

Answer (score 0):

To save data in a loop you need to index using some kind of iterator.

For example, compare the final result of `mydata` in this function:

```
for ii = 1:10;
    mydata = ii^2;
end
```

To that of:

```
mydata = zeros(10, 1); % Preallocate for performance
for ii = 1:10
    mydata(ii) = ii^2;
end
```

For the case where your iterator is not necessarily the same as your index, you can use a second iterator:

```
jj = 1;
mydata = zeros(10, 1);
for ii = 11:20
    mydata(jj) = ii^2;
    jj = jj + 1;
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. As i have told you I am newbie...in above case i am able to get Perunc separately for each case of q. But as iteration pass it is overwritten and after final the variable Perunc only has data of last iteration which is a vector . what i need is a matrix Perunc of dimension (length(Ebno)*length(q)) so that i can plot a 3d graph with Ebno in x axis q in y axis and Perunc in Z axis.